# How do I exclude a name from the results of a nested query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The following is my Employees table:

```
create table EMPLOYEES
(EmpID    char(4)         unique Not null,
 Ename    varchar(10),
 Job      varchar(9),
 MGR      char(4),
 Hiredate date,
 Salary   decimal(7,2),
 Comm     decimal(7,2),
 DeptNo   char(2)         not null,
     Primary key(EmpID),
     Foreign key(DeptNo) REFERENCES DEPARTMENTS(DeptNo));


insert into EMPLOYEES values (7839,'King','President',null,'17-Nov-11',5000,null,10);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7698,'Blake','Manager',7839,'01-May-11',2850,null,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7782,'Clark','Manager',7839,'02-Jun-11',2450,null,10);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7566,'Jones','Manager',7839,'02-Apr-11',2975,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7654,'Martin','Salesman',7698,'28-Feb-12',1250,1400,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7499,'Allen','Salesman',7698,'20-Feb-11',1600,300,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7844,'Turner','Salesman',7698,'08-Sep-11',1500,0,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7900,'James','Clerk',7698,'22-Feb-12',950,null,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7521,'Ward','Salesman',7698,'22-Feb-12',1250,500,30);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7902,'Ford','Analyst',7566,'03-Dec-11',3000,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7369,'Smith','Clerk',7902,'17-Dec-10',800,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7788,'Scott','Analyst',7566,'09-Dec-12',3000,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7876,'Adams','Clerk',7788,'12-Jan-10',1100,null,20);
insert into EMPLOYEES values (7934,'Miller','Clerk',7782,'23-Jan-12',1300,null,10);
```

The following is the DEPARTMENTS table:

```
create table DEPARTMENTS
    (DeptNo   char(2)  unique Not null,
     DName    varchar(14),
     Location varchar(13),
         Primary key(DeptNo));


insert into DEPARTMENTS values (10,'Accounting','New York');
insert into DEPARTMENTS values (20,'Research','Dallas');
insert into DEPARTMENTS Values (30,'Sales','Chicago');
insert into DEPARTMENTS values (40,'Operations','Boston');
```

The following is my query:

```
select ename, salary
from EMPLOYEES
where DeptNo in
(select DeptNo
from EMPLOYEES
where Ename ='blake');
```

How do I exclude 'blake' from my results?  I was told to use a `NOT IN` in the subquery but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ename, salary
from EMPLOYEES
where DeptNo in
(select DeptNo
from EMPLOYEES
where Ename ='blake') and Ename <>'blake';
```

You can also make use of `not in` as in second query.

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e563/5)

Comment: These are not giving me the correct results.  the statement with <> in it is giving me everybody but blake, but in everydepartment.  The statement with 'not in' is not giving me the correct results either.  Should I be using a GROUP BY statement?

Comment: wait, i am taking this in sqlfiddle and then we will have look at it.

Comment: @JeffOrris also paste department table for which deptno is foreign key

Comment: @Feelancer just pasted DEPARTMENTS table

Comment: @JeffOrris see the edit and go through the link i have made demo.

Comment: Thank you.  That program is pretty cool (SQLFIDDLE).  What is it capable of?

Comment: it gives you access to each and every thing MYSQL,Microsoft Server 2008,2005,etc

Comment: Nice,  I'll have to check it out.  Thank you for the help.  Also, is it appropriate to use GROUP BY when working with nested queries and aggregate functions?

Comment: Yes it is appropriate but it should be used only if its necessary, otherwise processing time will increase.

Comment: Thank you, you've been helpful.